# DeleteFile fails after CreateFile/Close handle in SYSTEM Service account

Tags: c++, security, service, file-access

I've written a DLL that is being loaded into a service process running as local system. Shouldn't I be able to delete the files I create?

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(m_achTempFilePath, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL) ;
```

succeeds. 
then I run `CloseHandle(hFile)`

and `DeleteFile(m_achTempFilePath)`

Delete file fails with access denied.

I executed the following and passed `&sa` as security attributes to `CreateFile` and then `DeleteFile` succeeds. But this gives everyone full control. I don't want that.

What's the proper way to do this?

```
CDacl dacl;
dacl.AddAllowedAce(Sids::World(), SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL | STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL) ;
CSecurityDesc sd;
sd.SetDacl(dacl);
CSecurityAttributes sa;
sa.Set(sd, true);
```

Comment: For the folder where the temp files are created, could its permissions be set to specifically deny a "Delete" operation (while allowing other operations)?  To check this, you can drill down into the folder's "Properties" context menu in Explorer and keep choosing the "Advanced" views for the SYSTEM user until you see "Delete" separated from other operations.

Comment: How can I see permissions for system user without taking ownership of the directory? I followed instructions [here](http://superuser.com/questions/172437/run-explorer-in-system-account-on-windows-vista-or-7-using-sysinternal-s-psexec). It'll start the start menu as system, but it always launches the explorer UI to traverse the file system as my local user account.

The directory is c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Temp\usgthrsvc if you want to check on your local computer.

Comment: Correction... I forgot. I moved to C:\ProgramData... I created a directory under the common app data directory. can create directories and files there, but cannot delete them in the service account running as local system.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the flag `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` in your create file method.  This way when you close the file's handle it will clean itself up.  The issue itself may be a timing based kernal issue with Windows.

This work around should resolve the issue.

Comment: I need a solution to the permissions problem. Not a work around. this isn't a timing issue. I cannot delete any files created when running in this security context. I can't delete or rename any files created by GetTempFileName either.